# How do we rearrange the terms of the harmonic series so they add up to 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, conditional-convergence

The harmonic series converges conditionally; therefore, the series can be rearranged in any way to get different sums, but how do we rearrange in such a way that it equates to 0. Is there a trick/ formula I could use to manipulate the series to equate it to 0 or to any number?

Comment: The ALTERNATING series corresponding with the harmonic series can be arranged this way, not the harmonic series itself.

Comment: Roughly speaking add positive terms until you get a non-negative value, add negative terms until you get a non-positive value and so on.

Comment: I know this has come up here before. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911293/summing-various-rearrangements-of-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-cdots isn't exactly it, but helpful.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623693/arranging-the-alternating-harmonic-series-to-sum-to-sqrt2

Answer (score 1):

I let do the task by Mathematica, and obtained a surprise:

[image]

We see here not a more or less random sequence of positive and negative terms, depending on arithmetic accidents, but a definite pattern: There are blocks of five subsequent terms of the following kind:
$${1\over 2n-1}, -{1\over 8n-6}, \ -{1\over 8n-4}, \ -{1\over 8n-2}, \ -{1\over 8n} \qquad(n\geq1)\ .$$
I hope that someone will be able to prove that the sequence will go on forever like that.

Comment: Yes this works.  My previous answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1623739/442